# Rollover list with the first child already activated?

Tags: css, list, menu, hover, rollover

Sorry for my poor english, I'm french !

The first `li` is already in red, but I want classical rollover effect (only css)

```
<ul>
    <li>1111</li>
    <li>2222</li>
    <li>3333</li>
</ul>
```

with

```
li:first-child { color: red; }
li:hover { color: red; }
ul:hover li:first-child { color: black; }
li:first-child:hover { color: red; }
```

The last line doesn't work : When my mouse is over 1111, he becomes black instead of stay red.

Look here please : http://jsfiddle.net/cP5rQ/3/

And thank you for advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to increase the [specificity](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/) of your last rule enough so that it becomes at least equal to the specificity of the third rule; it will then override the third rule and the item will become red as it should.

Do this by writing the last rule as

```
ul:hover li:first-child:hover { color: red; }​
```

**[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/QGLqH/)**.

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick. Is this what you wanted?

```
li:first-child { color: red; }
ul:hover li:first-child { color: black; }
li:hover { color: red; }
ul:hover li:first-child:hover { color: red; }​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cP5rQ/6/

Comment: Yes. Thanks. CSS is precise !